# What is the difference between extractStrictEntity and toStrictEntity in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka-http

What is the difference between `extractStrictEntity` and `toStrictEntity`? 
Here is the `extractStrictEntity` route code:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val route = extractStrictEntity(3.seconds) { entity =>
  complete(entity.data.utf8String)
}
```

And here is the `toStrictEntity` route code:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val route = toStrictEntity(3.seconds) { entity =>
  complete(entity.data.utf8String)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second route, the one with `toStrictEntity`, doesn't compile; it fails with:

```
value data is not a member of akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext
```

---

As for the distinction between the two directives, [`extractStrictEntity`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.1.1/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/BasicDirectives.scala#L336) calls `toStrictEntity`:

```
def extractStrictEntity(timeout: FiniteDuration): Directive1[HttpEntity.Strict] =
  toStrictEntity(timeout) & extract(_.request.entity.asInstanceOf[HttpEntity.Strict])

// ...

def toStrictEntity(timeout: FiniteDuration): Directive0 =
// ...
```

The following two routes are essentially the same:

```
val route1 = extractStrictEntity(3.seconds) { entity =>
  complete(entity.data.utf8String)
}

val route2 = toStrictEntity(3.seconds) {
  extractRequest { req =>
    req.entity match {
      case strict: HttpEntity.Strict =>
        complete(strict.data.utf8String)
      case _ =>
        complete("Request entity is not strict!")
    }
  }
}
```

`extractStrictEntity` returns a `Directive1[HttpEntity.Strict]`, meaning it extracts a single `HttpEntity.Strict` value. On the other hand, `toStrictEntity` returns a `Directive0`, meaning it extracts nothing--hence the nested call to `extractRequest` in the above example.

Comment: can i apply any one of this for exception `'Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.`